# Prevent child from expanding to fit available width

Tags: java, javafx

I have a styled javafx `Node` (here referred to as `myLabel`) which needs to be a certain size (determined by its contents). I'm placing it in a `GridPane`, and if the containing column of the pane is large enough, the node expands to fill the extra space, but I want it to maintain its original size.

```
GridPane pane = new GridPane();
GridPane.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);

ColumnConstraints col0 = new ColumnConstraints();
col0.setHalignment(HPos.LEFT);
col0.setPrefWidth(300);
pane.getColumnConstraints().add(col0);

pane.add(myLabel, 0, 0);
```

In the above case, `myLabel` takes up the entire `300px` width it has available, but I only want it to use the space that it needs.

I've tried setting `GridPane.setHgrow(myLabel, Priority.NEVER)`, but this isn't having the effect I'm expecting (that the label will no longer be allocated additional space). I don't want to use `myLabel.setMaxSize(...,...)`, as this gets in the way of the label having dynamic size, and I don't want to set any arbitrary constraints on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the option I was looking for was not `setHgrow(myLabel, Priority.NEVER)`, but `setFillWidth(myLabel, false)`.
It looks like `setHgrow` affects the size of the area containing the node, optionally increasing the size if there is more space available, whereas `setFillWidth` affects the size of the contained node, optionally increasing its dimensions to fit the size of the area containing it.

[Source](https://amyfowlersblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/javafx-1-3-growing-shrinking-and-filling/)

Answer (score 0):

Set Min,Max and Pref Width to 'USE_COMPUTED_SIZE'.

```
myLabel.setMinWidth(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
myLabel.setMaxWidth(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
myLabel.setPrefWidth(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```